# Creating frendly url

Tags: .htaccess

I'm struggling with it all day. I try to create friendly urls to my localhost. My site link is for example `www.example.com` and when i for example want see news i want to link from `www.example.com/news.php` look like `www.example.com/news` and i did this with this code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

And everything is worked but i want to also my posts and users and other dont look like `www.example.com/users/?id=1` or for posts `www.example.com/posts/?id=3231` i want to have like this `www.example.com/users/1` or `www.example.com/posts/3231` and at the same time my php files dont have .php extensions. So basicly i want `www.example.com/somepage.php` to `www.example.com/somepage` and `www.example.com/somepage.php?somevalue=something` to `www.example.com/somepage/something`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this in your .htaccess in the root.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(users|posts)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1/?id=$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?somevalue=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks this is working for me :) just a one question. Can I use this only on page user.php and posts.php or i can use it on any .php file?

Comment: Well the last rule can be any PHP file.  The first rule looks only for `users/value` and `posts/value`